# Among the following, which is closest to $\sqrt{0.016}$?

Tags: contest-math, fractions, gre-exam

Among the following, which is closest in value to $\sqrt{0.016}$?

A. $0.4$

B. $0.04$

C. $0.2$

D. $0.02$

**E. $0.13$**

**My Approach:**

$(\frac{16}{1000})^\frac{1}{2} = (\frac{4}{250})^\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{5\cdot\sqrt{10}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{5\cdot\sqrt{5}}$

But I don't know how to reach to answer.

Thank You!

Comment: $\sqrt{0.016} = \dfrac{\sqrt{1.6}}{10}= \dfrac{\sqrt{160}}{100}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just square:

$0.4^2=0.16$

$0.04^2=0.0016$

$0.2^2=0.04$

$0.02^2=0.0004$

$0.13^2=0.0169$

Can you choose?

Comment: Seriously i don't know why i missed that and went for long way. Thank You so much.

Answer (score 6):

Though squaring each and checking works equally as well, here's another way to figure it out:
$$
\sqrt{0.016}=\frac{\sqrt{1000}}{\sqrt{1000}}\sqrt{0.016}=\frac{\sqrt{16}}{\sqrt{1000}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{1000}}\approx\frac{4}{\sqrt{1024}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{2^{10}}}=\frac{4}{2^{5}}=\frac{4}{32}=\frac{1}{8}=0.125
$$

Comment: I am amazed with the solution, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you rationalize the denominator of your ratio to get $ \ \frac{ \sqrt{10} }{25} \ $ , you can use the fact that $ \ \sqrt{10} \ $ is a little bigger than 3 to estimate that the number in question is a bit larger than $ \ \frac{3}{25} \ = \ 0.12 \ $ .  No other choice but (E)  is close to that.

Comment: To be a bit more precise without needing careful error estimates from calculus you might just argue that it's between $\frac{3}{25}=0.12$ and $\frac{4}{25}=0.16$.

Comment: Granted, though I wasn't using any "careful" estimate -- it's only needful here to see that the numerator has to be much closer to  3  than to  5  , which would give the next nearest fraction with the right order of magnitude among the choices, $ \ \frac{5}{25} \ = \ 0.2 \ $ .  (If one works with numbers a lot, one might already know that $ \ \sqrt{10} \ \approx \ 3.16 \ $  . )

Answer (score 0):

This absolutely is the worst way to solve this problem, but I though it might be useful to you, or at least interesting (I bet ability to evaluate things numerically on paper *is* something interesting).

From \begin{align}\sqrt{0.016}&=\sqrt{16\cdot10^{-3}}=4\sqrt{10^{-1}10^{-2}}=4\cdot10^{-1}\sqrt{10^{-1}}=\frac4{10}\sqrt{1\over10}=\frac25\frac1{\sqrt{10}}\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{10}}=\\&=\frac25\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10}=\frac1{25}\sqrt{10}\end{align}
you can always evaluate $\sqrt{10}$ (or any square root, and many other different things) numerically to arbitrary precision with *numerical root finding algorithms*, which given some function $$f:D\subseteq\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R$$ and (for most of them) some initial guess $$x_0\in D$$ will provide $x_n\in D$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=0,$$ that is, the bigger the $n$ gets (more *iterations* of the algorithm are computed), the more accurate the result $x_n$ gets relative to the actual root $x:\,f(x)=0$. The simplest algorithm is via Newton and goes like this: you want $\sqrt{10}$, i.e. some $x$ such that $x^2=10$, that is, $x^2-10=0$; let $$f(x)=x^2-10.$$
Then by Newton's method you need to *[differentiate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative)* that to get $$f'(x)=2x,$$ and also set some initial guess $x_0$, for which $$x_0=3$$ seems reasonable. The first step goes like this:
$$x_1=x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}=3-\frac{9-10}6=3+\frac16=\frac{19}6;$$
the second one:
$$x_2=x_1-\frac{f(x_1)}{f'(x_1)}=\frac{19}6-\frac{361/36-10}{38/6}=\frac{19}6-\frac{1/36}{38/6}=\frac{19}6-\frac1{6\cdot38}=\frac{721}{228};$$
you get the idea. Each step produces bigger and bigger nominators and denominators, which ratio approaches $\sqrt{10}$. Long division yields $$x_2=\frac{721}{228}=3.16\overline{228070175438596491\,\,}\approx3.16228,$$ which with $$x=\sqrt{10}=3.16227766016837933199889\dotsc\approx3.16228$$ is accurate to **six** figures (and only via *two* iterations).

Now, dividing $3.16228$ by $25$ (remember to cut off at the sixth significant figure to avoid [overprecision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision) — you ain't have no more information!) yields $$0.12649,$$ which shows that $0.13$ is the closet number in the given set to $\sqrt{0.016}\,.$